# Flask SQLAlchemy query with order_by returns error no such column

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my models:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Person, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Person id:{self.id} name:{self.name}>'

class Pet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pets'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('persons.id'), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Pet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Pet id:{self.id} name:{self.name} owner_id:{self.owner_id}>'
```

I`m trying to get persons list ordered by count of pets with this query:

```
persons = Person.query.order_by(Person.pets).all()
```

And getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: pets.owner_id
[SQL: SELECT persons.id AS persons_id, persons.name AS persons_name
FROM persons ORDER BY persons.id = pets.owner_id]
```

What I`m doing wrong?
I have a suggestion that I need to make a request with join(), but research in google did not give working solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the SQL, you'll note that there is no FROM item `pets`, and so `ORDER BY persons.id = pets.owner_id` fails. This happens because the relationship attribute `Person.pets` renders as its `ON` clause in query context, or in other words as `persons.id = pets.owner_id`. There are many ways to form the proper query, for example using a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
Person.query.\
    outerjoin(Person.pets).\
    group_by(Person.id).\
    order_by(func.count(Pet.id)).\
    all()
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ensures that persons without pets are considered as well.

Comment: This query worked for me with some modification. In my case used `db.func.count(Pet.id)` instead of `func.count(Pet.id)`.